# Custom Item Preference has large font style and bugs

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-preference-v14

I facing with this problem many times and always leaving it for the best times ;)
But now I want to get a solution. In all my apps I can't make preference screens with Preference Support libs properly. Always I get some view issues such as:

*On a picture below you can see Custom child preference (item #2) has another styles than native preference item above. It has large font in title and SeekBar thumb is cropped, other margins*

[image]

In gradle I'm using:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:preference-v14:24.1.1'
```

With overriding in a manifest:

```
<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.v14.preference"/>
```

I googling very-very long time and browsed large amount of android xml information. But I fail and stuck on this. I don't want use any libs, I want to learn and understand the issue. Thanks!